# How to "disturb" an image with noise, but keep the orginal undisturbed pixel intact, and write to file in imagesc

Tags: matlab

For simple explanation of the title, imagine you're using a Photoshop layers, where noise is on the top layer.

```
% load a test image
I = rgb2gray(imread('peppers.png'));

% recreate image
cmap = colormap();          % grab current colormap
ncolors = size(cmap,1);
% do what imagesc does
Iind = double(I) - double(min(I(:)));
Iind = Iind / max(Iind(:));
% quantize image
Iind = round(Iind * ncolors + 0.5);
Iind(Iind > ncolors) = ncolors;
Iind(Iind < 1) = 1;
% convert to RGB from indexed image using cmap as palette
Irgb = ind2rgb(Iind,cmap);

imwrite(Irgb, 'filename.bmp');
```

These code will scale the colormap and write to file. However, by adding a artificial noise at a certain pixel location after loaded the image:

```
I(50,50) = rand(1);
```

This will generate a completely different colormap visually, and the one with the noise will look a little washed out. Top image is the original and bottom is with noise.
[image: Without any noise]
[image: With noise added]

**EDIT**: The below image is the cropped image on the top left corner. Left is original and right is with noise. On the right you can see the color washed out a little bit, and if you look closely you can see a noise (dark blue color, position (50,50)).

[image: Compare]

Any idea how to still maintain the original after noise was added? Thanks in advance!

Comment: To me the two linked pictures look identical. Could you maybe highlight differences?

Comment: If you look closely the canvas at the back is the most obvious, it has a little washed out.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure I see an effect.

Comment: I can't see an effect either. `Top image is the original and bottom is with original.` What does this mean? Which one is the original?

Comment: Sorry that was typo. Actually you don't need to see the image to know the differences. If a noise was added, the pixel intensity changes, thus the scale will be different, and so the output image color will be scaled.

Comment: If you skip the part where you stretch the intensity range of the image, then this effect will not occur. There is no way of increasing the range by adding noise and at the same time not changing the range. So you need to pick: either don’t stretch, or don’t change the range.

Comment: But if you skip that part, the image will be too bright and it became a singular color, hmmm..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're adding noise (between 0 and 1) to the original image which has `min = 8` and `max = 255`. This is reducing the new min to either 0 or 1 (the input image is of type `uint8`, and it seems MATLAB rounds the random number) which stretches out the colourmap slightly. There are two options to avoid this.

#### Add random noise in the range of the original image

```matlab
I(50,50) = randi([min(I(:)), max(I(:))]);
```

#### Add random noise after scaling the original image

```matlab
Irgb(50,50) = rand(1);
```